# Spring - Combing Java Config and Xml to reference a bean defined in legacy XML

Tags: spring, configuration

Is it possible to configure a classpath resource for a Java bean in any other location in the classpath than src/main/resources?  I have an application which picks up its configuration files from  src/main/app/conf/beans.xml. I want to use the bean defined in the xml configuration in my JavaConfig configuration, how can I specify the location in a JavaConfig file, for example something like below?

```
   @Configuration
   @ImportResource("classpath:..beans.xml)
   public class AppConfig{
     // Reference Bean
      @Autowired
      private MessageLoader loader;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is certainly possible. If your resources are not present in `src/main/resources` then, you can specify that directory in your POM.

```
<resource>
           <directory>[your folder here]</directory>
</resource>
```

Reference [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html)

Comment: Thank you, I prefer this method.

Comment: Thank you, very much.  Gratefully appreciated!